# File larger than 1mb upload again and again in the upload folder

Tags: php

If we upload a file larger than 1 MB it uploads accurately but upload the same file again and again without showing any notification. Upload Folder shows `same file uploaded again and again`. Can you please help me out to resolve this issue?

```php
$this->load->language('extension/ticketform');
$json = array();

foreach ($this->request->files as $key => $value) {
     $_FILES['img']['name'] = $value['name'];
     $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'];
}

if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])) {

    $imageCount = count($_FILES['img']['name']);

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($imageCount);exit;
    for($i=0;$i<$imageCount;$i++) {

        if ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i] == '') {
            continue;
        }
        //Get file extension    
        $filename  = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];  
        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newname = date('YmdHis', time()) . mt_rand() . '.'. $extension;
      
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i], DIR_DOWNLOAD . $newname);

        $json['filename'][] = $newname;
        $json['mask'] = $filename;
    }
} else {
    $json['error'] = '<strong>Error!! </strong> Please select a file.';
}
$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_upload');
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

Comment: _..same file uploaded again and again..._ This still doesn't help us to understand what you are trying to ask/achieve versus what is going wrong here

Comment: I am trying to solve the issue of file duplication. If we upload a large file (more than 1MB) then the code upload the same file again and again with the different file number. The different file number is not the issue, my only concern is why upload the same file again and again.

Comment: Can anybody check if mod_security is the culprit of this issue.?

Comment: _..my only concern is why upload the same file again and again..._ Why shouldn't it? You don't do any checks in your code to see if the file already exists before uploading

Comment: how can we add validation, every time when file uploaded we changed the file name.

Comment: So your upload is in a loop?1 file uploaded more than 2 times in one session?

Comment: the problem is probably with the count($_Files and the loop for($i=0;$i<$imageCount;$i++) { what exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: The issue is not in the above code, cron job creating some issues, i have fixed these issues, Thanks, everyone.